# Saving jQueries plugin data to string won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying hand in developing my first jQuery plugin and I've run into many pitfalls. Plugin itself is a range-slider of some kind that works with multiple instances on one page with different settings.

Anyhow, I've run into many problems, first of all, I can't retrieve and change my plugins settings after it's initiated. So far I've used both google and SO and now I've run into another problem. Every tutorial, solution uses `var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('name');` for easy accessing plugins options/settings. I use it too but somehow I can't retrieve the saved data. Here's my code:

```
;(function ($) {
    var settings = {
        min: 20,
        max: 100,
        step: .1,
        vertical: false,
        defaultValue: 20,
        onMouseUpFn: function() {},
        onSlideChange: function() {}
    };

    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('slider');/*,
                    // won't work. why?
                    settings = {
                        min: 20,
                        max: 100,
                        step: .1,
                        defaultValue: 20,
                        vertical: false,
                        onMouseUpArea: false,
                        onMouseUpFn: function () {},
                        onSliderChange: function() {}
                    };*/

                if(options) {$.extend(settings, options); }

                if(!data) {
                    var defaultData = {
                        target:$this,
                        settings:settings,
                        slider:$this.find('.sliderrr'),
                        sliderWidth:$this.find('.sliderrr').width(),
                        valueText:$this.find('.sliderrr span')
                    };

                    data = $this.data('slider', defaultData);
                }

                console.log([
                    data.data('slider'),
                    $().jquery // "1.7.2"
                ]);
                /*[
                Object
                    settings: Object
                        defaultValue: "56.3"
                        max: "56.3"
                        min: 20
                        onMouseUpFn: function () {}
                        onSlideChange: function () {}
                        step: 0.1
                        vertical: false
                        __proto__: Object
                    slider: e.fn.e.init[1]
                    sliderWidth: 10
                    target: e.fn.e.init[1]
                    valueText: e.fn.e.init[1]
                    __proto__: Object
                ]*/

                if(data.settings.vertical) { // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vertical' of undefined
                    data = $.extend(data, {
                        barOffset: $this.find('.barrr').offset().top,
                        barLength: $this.find('.barrr').height() - data.sliderWidth
                    });
                } else {
                    data = $.extend(data, {
                        barOffset: $this.find('.barrr').offset().left,
                        barLength: $this.find('.barrr').width() - data.sliderWidth
                    });
                }

                data.slider.mousedown(function(e) {
                    // slider's logic
                });

                $this.data('slider', data);
            });
        },
        setOptions: function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var data = $(this).data('slider');
                var settings = data.settings; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

                if(options) {
                    settings = $.extend(settings, options);
                    data = $.extend(data, settings);

                    $(this).data('slider', data);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.sliderrr = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            return $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist in slider');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I've added errors that I get as comments and console log of the object. Here is jsFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/RJkA2/

I've been messing with this for almost 2 days now, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also remove errors from your code, now it works, demo: [jsfiddle.net/RJkA2/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/RJkA2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I changed your init function:

```
if(!data) {
    var defaultData = {
        target:$this,
        settings:settings,
        slider:$this.find('.sliderrr'),
        sliderWidth:$this.find('.sliderrr').width(),
        valueText:$this.find('.sliderrr span')
    };
    $this.data('slider', defaultData); //setting data doesn't return the data!
    data=$this.data('slider');
}
console.log([$this.data('slider'), $().jquery]); //"data.data" was written here by mistake
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RJkA2/1/

Hope this helps!